# Execute shell script using Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Suppose I have a shell script stored in a GCS bucket. Is it possible to execute it using Apache Beam? If yes, then how?
I haven't currently tried anything for it yet as I couldn't find anything of this sort in the documentations for Apache Beam or Dataflow. So just wanted to know what approach I must take for it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's unusual, but not unheard of to want to execute a whole shell script from something like a `DoFn`. Is this what you want to do? Do you want to run it once for each element in a `PCollection`?

If so, you'd want to use the [GCS API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get), or [the FileSystems API](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileSystems.html) to obtain the whole contents of the shell script into a String or byte array, and then pass it as a side input into your `ParDo`.

Then you can execute it using a tool like `subprocess` in Python, or `ProcessBuilder` in Java.

Let me know if you need something more specific, and we can iterate a solution.

Comment: Hi Pablo, I know it is an old question but I would like to run a similar scenario. I have two shell commands from a library that was uploaded to the worker with the setup.py script Running. The first command is a configuration command and the second is an execution that is dependant on the config command. I tried separating them with ';' or '&&' at the subprocess with no success. i tried also os.system with both commands and it didn't work out. I can not separate them because the second subporcess will not have the first subporcess configuration setting. please let me know your thoughts. thx

Comment: You may be able to do something like this: `subprocess.call(['sh', '-c', 'echo "hi" && echo "why"']) ` - except you replace your two commands. Is that possible?